# How python XLRD library scans all sheets in excel?

Tags: python, excel

I am planning to use XLRD libraries for reading the number of rows and columns in the excel file that I imported.

I use following codes which work perfectly fine.

```
    import xlrd
    path = 'sample123.xlsx'
    inputWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    inputWorksheet = inputWorkbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    print("Your worksheet has: " + str(inputWorksheet.nrows) + " rows")
    print("Your worksheet has: " + str(inputWorksheet.ncols) + " columns")
```

However, that codes only run for a sheet (the first one). If I would like to randomly import a number of excel files that I do not know the total index or sheet names of each file, is there any coding suggestion so that all sheets in that file could be scanned through, thus the number of rows and columns for all sheets can be detected?

Thanks very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> However, that codes only run for a sheet (the first one)

that is because you are passing the index=0 when calling get sheet method...

you call the method `get_sheet`

```
myDoc.get_sheet(index)
```

where index is the index of the sheet, if you dont know it, you can find it by name:

```
sheet_names().index(nameOfMySheet)
```

here the [doc](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/xlrd.Book.sheet_names)

[here](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/xlrd.sheet.Sheet) is an example about how to get the sheets in a workbook

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("sample.xls")
for sheet in book.sheets():
    print sheet.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, if I randomly import a number of excel files (without knowing the sheet name or total index number of each file), is there any coding suggestion to just read all sheets in the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

To read all sheets from one excel file by using xlrd,

```
import xlrd
path = 'sample123.xlsx'
inputWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

dict_sheet_tabs= {} # Store sheets in a dictionary

for sheet_name in inputWorkbook.sheet_names():
  print(sheet_name ) # name of each tab
  all_sheet = wb1.sheet_by_name(sheet_name) # read sheet by name
  dict_sheet_tabs.update({sheet_name:all_sheet })

print(dict_sheet_tabs)

>>> {'sheet_name1': <xlrd.sheet.Sheet object at 0x7fa903b6efd0>, 'sheet_name2': <xlrd.sheet.Sheet object at 0x7fa9038ece10>}
#The dictionary keys are sheet names and values are the sheet content
```